# redirect going to the link then redirecting to the main website in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, validation

I have code written in codeigniter having a redirect() shown as below :

```
   if(isset($_POST['Search'])) 
   {
    $link = SITE_URL."generate_prn/";
    if($this->input->post('cin')){  
    $link .= "cin/".$this->input->post('cin')."/";  
    }
   $this->session->set_userdata('link',$link);
   redirect($link,'refresh');
   $data['list']=$_POST;
  }
```

$link has the value http://website.com/accounts/registration/generate_prn/cin/17ASA10000/. In the above code, it is redirecting to the value of $link given above then it redirects again to the website http://website.com/. I don't want it to redirect to the website but it should stay in the link value given above. Can anyone help me out in this and how to prevent it from going to the main website?

Full code (`generate_prn.php`) is

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Generate_prn extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        if (!$this->session->userdata('user_id')) {
            redirect('login/', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    public function index() {
        if (isset($_POST['Search'])) {
            $link = SITE_URL . "generate_prn/";
            if ($this->input->post('cin')) {
                $link .= "cin/" . $this->input->post('cin') . "/";
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata('link', $link);
            redirect($link, 'refresh');
            $data['list'] = $_POST;
        } else {
            $data['info'] = '';
            $uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(4);
            $aim = $uri['aim'];
            if ($uri['cin'] != '') {
                $cin = $uri['cin'];

                if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
                    $receipt_date = $this->input->post('receipt_date');
                    $timestamp = strtotime($receipt_date);
                    $date = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
                    $action = $data['stud_competition_data']['status'];
                    /* echo $action;exit; */
                    switch ($action):
                        case 'NOT_REG' :

                            $validate_data = array(
                                'receipt_number' => $this->input->post('receipt_number'),
                                'receipt_date' => $this->input->post('receipt_date'),
                                'branch_name' => $this->input->post('branch_name')
                            );

                            $this->validation->set_rules('branch_name', 'branch_name', 'required');
                            if ($this->validation->run() === FALSE) {
                                //var_dump($this->validation->show_errors());
                                $this->notifications->notify('Please make all entries', 'error');
                            } else {
                                $regstration_data = array(
                                    'competition_schedule_id' => $competition_schedule_id,
                                    'student_id' => $student_id,
                                    'receipt_number' => $receipt_number,
                                    'branch_name' => $branch_name,
                                    'receipt_date' => $date,
                                    'frcode' => $frcode,
                                    'period_name' => $period_name,
                                    'levelcode' => $levelcode,
                                    'period' => $period_id
                                ); else {
                                    echo $this->notifications->notify('Registration failed', 'error');
                                }
                                redirect('accounts/generate_prn', 'refresh');
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'ALREADY_REG':
                            $validate_data = array(
                                'receipt_number' => $this->input->post('receipt_number'),
                                'receipt_date' => $this->input->post('receipt_date'),
                                'branch_name' => $this->input->post('branch_name')
                            );
                            $this->validation->set_data($validate_data);
                            $this->validation->set_rules('receipt_number', 'receipt_number', 'required');
                            $this->validation->set_rules('receipt_date', 'receipt_date', 'required');
                            $this->validation->set_rules('branch_name', 'branch_name', 'required');
                            if ($this->validation->run() === FALSE) {
                                //var_dump($this->validation->show_errors());
                                $this->notifications->notify('Please make all entries', 'error');
                            } else {



                                /* $timestamp      = strtotime($reciept_date);
                                  $date           = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp); */
                                $prn_no = $data['stud_competition_data']['upcoming_schedule_deatils'][0]['permenent_registration_number'];
                                if (empty($prn_no)) {
                                    $regstration_data = array(
                                        'competition_registration_id' => $competition_registration_id,
                                        'competition_schedule_id' => $competition_schedule_id,
                                        'student_id' => $student_id,
                                        'receipt_number' => $receipt_number,
                                        'branch_name' => $branch_name,
                                        'receipt_date' => $date,
                                        'frcode' => $frcode,
                                        'period_name' => $period_name,
                                        'period' => $period_id,
                                        'levelcode' => $levelcode,
                                    );
                                    $comp_reg_status = $this->accountsmodel->generate_prn($regstration_data);
                                } else {
                                    //echo "prn no empty";exit;

                                    $comp_reg_status = $this->accountsmodel->update_reg_details($regstration_data);
                                }
                                /* echo "<pre>";print_r($regstration_data);exit;     */
                                if ($comp_reg_status) {
                                    echo $this->notifications->notify('REGISTRATION DETAILS UPDETED', 'success');
                                } else {
                                    echo $this->notifications->notify('Registration failed', 'error');
                                }
                                redirect('accounts/generate_prn', 'refresh');
                            }
                            break;
                    endswitch;
                }
                //redirect('accounts/registration/generate_prn', 'refresh');  
            } /* end of if of uri['cin']!='' */ else {
                $data['info'] = "empty";
            } /* END OF ELSE if of uri['cin']!='' */
        }
        $this->load->view("prn_generation.php", $data);
    }

}

?>
```

I have another page containing an input box and a submit button with the name `Search`. After inputting a value in the input box and when submitting the value in the input box it goes to the `generate_prn.php` file.

Comment: make sure u not have any redirect in generate_prn method

Comment: The php code I have written above is in the generate_prn.php file which is a controller file

Comment: sorry taking about the method u redirect from here

Comment: there is also 2 or 3 redirect() written in this file

Comment: didnt understand..

Comment: show your full code

Comment: I have updated the full code above

Comment: Anyone here ?...

Comment: Something **after** the above code in method `cin` is redirecting to `website.com` as there is no logic for it to do that in the code you posted.